# Corrupted USB Drive

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive

Got a Flash 32Gb drive which goes corrupted.
Here are some screenshots:

[image]
[image]

The driver is corrected installed but I cannot access the drive.
How I solve it? I have tried with several disk and partitions recovery tools.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Get Data Back](http://download.cnet.com/GetDataBack/3000-2094_4-10061631.html) , I have used it in the past and it is very easy to use and usually gets the job done. My hard drive crashed entirely and i was able to get all my data back. If all methods of data recovery has failed your only option is to full format to be able to use the drive again.

Comment: The question concerned a USB drive not a hard drive.

Comment: GetDataBack doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

I used with success TestDisk http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk , It's not-so-easy but there is good documentation.

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried using different speed USB? For example I had a corrupted hard disk and was able to restore some data only when using a old usb (USB 1.X) port... anyway if TestDisk does not work, I don't know what could work. Maybe trying reading it from different computer? Once I was able to read a corrupted SD card from Linux and dump it to image file with dd. The same SD card was impossible to read from Win utilities. In both these examples, the idea is the same: change as much as you can, port, protocol, computer, operating system. It's a matter of luck...